# What is the difference between AWS PrivateLink and VPC Peering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Is VPC Peering secure? Do VPC Peering and PrivateLink not use an internet gateway or any other gateway?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**VPC Peering** allows connectivity between two VPCs. It's just like normal routing between network segments.

[VPC PrivateLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html) allows you to publish an "endpoint" that others can connect with from their own VPC. It's similar to a normal **VPC Endpoint**, but instead of connecting to an AWS service, people can connect to your endpoint. Think of it as a way to publish a private API endpoint without having to go via the Internet.

In both cases, no traffic goes across the Internet. Connectivity is directly between the VPCs.

Comment: Thanks John, Can you explain more about the difference between PrivateLink and Endpiont? They look identical to me.

Comment: @MaYaN A VPC Endpoint uses PrivateLink "behind the scenes" to provide access to an AWS API. PrivateLink also lets you expose an endpoint to _your own service_ (which is not possible with a VPC Endpoint).

Comment: can PrivateLinks connect with VPCs in another region? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: @AbhayNayak Found this: [AWS PrivateLink now supports access over Inter-Region VPC Peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-privatelink-now-supports-access-over-inter-region-vpc-peering/)

Answer (score 27):

#### VPC Peering `vs` PrivateLink

These 2 developed separately, but have more recently found themselves intertwined.

- VPC Peering - applies to VPC
- PrivateLink - applies to Application/Service

With **VPC Peering** you connect your VPC to another VPC. Both VPC owners are
involved in setting up this connection. When one VPC, (the visiting) wants
to access a resource on the other (the visited), the connection need not
go through the internet.

**PrivateLink** provides a convenient way to connect to applications/services 
by name with added security. You configure your application/service in your 
VPC as an AWS PrivateLink-powered service (referred to as an endpoint service). 
AWS generates a specific DNS hostname for the service. Other AWS principals 
can create a connection to your endpoint service after you grant them permission.

**VPC Peering + PrivateLink**

**As of March 7, 2019, applications in a VPC can now securely access AWS
PrivateLink endpoints across VPC peering connections**. AWS PrivateLink
endpoints can now be accessed across both intra- and inter-region VPC peering
connections. [More on this](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/aws-privatelink-now-supports-access-over-vpc-peering/)

**Notes on VPC Peering**

> **VPC peering** allows VPC resources including ... to communicate with each 
>   other using private IP addresses, without requiring gateways, VPN connections, 
>   or separate network appliances. ...Traffic always stays on the global AWS 
>   backbone, and never traverses the public internet
>
> Inter-Region VPC Peering provides a simple and cost-effective way to share 
>   resources between regions or replicate data for geographic redundancy.

[AWS - What is VPC Peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html)

**Notes on Endpoint Services**

> When you create a **VPC endpoint service**, AWS generates endpoint-specific DNS
>   hostnames that you can use to communicate with the service. These names
>   include the VPC endpoint ID, the Availability Zone name and Region Name, for
>   example, `vpce-1234-abcdev-us-east-1.vpce-svc-123345.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com`.
>   By default, your consumers access the service with that DNS name
>
> When you create an endpoint, you can attach an endpoint policy to it that
>   controls access to the *related* service
>
> An endpoint policy does not override or replace IAM user policies or
>   service-specific policies (such as S3 bucket policies). It is a separate
>   policy for controlling access from the endpoint to the specified service.

- [AWS Endpoint access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html)
- [AWS VPC Endpoint access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-access.html)

Answer (score 17):

Let's understand this by a real-life use case

1. Suppose You have your Own VPC (created by you using your own AWS Account) in which you have few EC2 instances that wants to communicate with instances running in your Client's VPC - obviously this VPC is created by your client using his/her AWS Account - Use VPC Peering to achieve this communication requirement
2. Now consider you have your OWN VPC (created by you using your own AWS Account) with EC2 Instance running inside it, and using the same AWS account you uploaded some files in S3.
   And your EC2 Instance now wants to read content of the file in S3.

In this case you will configure VPC Endpoint - which uses PrivateLink technology - AWS PrivateLink allows you to privately access services hosted on the AWS network in a highly available and scalable manner, without using public IPs and without requiring the traffic to traverse the internet.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Although multiple scenario when to choose VPC peering over AWS PrivateLink or vice-versa but few use case:-
**When to use VPC peering connection over AWS Private Link.**

1. Peering two or more VPCs to provide full access to resources
2. Peering to one VPC to access centralized resources
3. Peering with Classic Link

**When to use AWS PrivateLink over VPC peering connection**

1. Acceptor VPC have a CIDR block that overlaps with the CIDR block of the requester VPC. In this case you can try with PrivateLink

Answer (score -5):

VPC peering is service by AWS to facilitate communications between 2 VPC in the same or different region. I would prefer to set up a VPC peering between 2 private subnets, so the EC2 instances in the private subnets can connect to each other as if they are part of the same network.

VPC Private Link is a way of making your service available to set of consumers. You can expose a service and the consumers can consume your service by creating an endpoint for your service.

VPC as a service provided by AWS can be accessed over the internet. It does not mean it is unsecured. In AWS console you can make the customized configuration as per your requirements for network security and make your network more secure.

There are many features provided by AWS using which you can make your VPC secure.

More details are shared in the below article

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Security.html